# MaterialUI `onBlur` doesn't work on TextField component --> any alternative?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to run a handler `onBlur` of an input TextField (material UI component). However, mUI doesn't seem to provide this for the TextField component. How would I work-around this?

[mUI TextField](https://mui.com/api/text-field/)

```
// doesn't work for TextField component -->
..
<div className="flex w-2/8">
    <TextField
        sx={{ width: '100%', marginRight: '5px' }}
        id="outlined-adornment-amount"
        value={values.increase}
        onBlur={handleChange('increase')}
        label="Increase"
        type="number"
        inputProps={{
            inputMode: 'numeric',
            pattern: '[0-9]*',
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
        }}
        InputProps={{
            startAdornment: <InputAdornment position="start">%</InputAdornment>
        }}
    />
</div>

// works --> 

..
        onChange={handleChange('increase')}
..
```

Comment: That doesn't work. `onBlur={() => handleChange(‘increase’)}` is the correct syntax.

Comment: @BiciAP that doesnt seem to work either :(

Comment: Then what does `handleChange` do? I could only guess that what happens in the function is the problem.